# How to draw NSProgressIndicator correctly on Big Sur NSStatusBar?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-big-sur

[image]

[image]

[image]

Before OS X Big Sur it was working fine (screenshots 2 and 3) using this code:

```
let prog = NSProgressIndicator(frame: NSMakeRect(1, 2, 18, 18))
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

prog.style = .spinning
prog.isIndeterminate = false
statusItem.button?.addSubview(prog)
statusItem.menu = statusMenu
```

But after update, it appears with 4 corners and empty inside (first screenshot).

Any idea how to fix?

UPDATE 1:
After following [El Tomato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1824524/el-tomato) suggestions:

```
prog.controlSize = .small
prog.controlTint = .blueControlTint
prog.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight)
```

it looks like this:

[image]

But how to make it look as in Catalina (Pie chart)

Comment: Trying setting the size to 16, 16.

Comment: This way it appears completely transparent. Nothing is visible on the statusMenu bar. It's invisible.

Comment: Change the color of the spinner to white (brightest, highest saturation) with `Color Controls`.

Comment: Added Update1. Still not as before. Thanks for helping anyway.